# Naming conventions for overload parameters in typescript

Tags: typescript, conventions

I need to have a function which takes in parameter as string or array of string.

```
delete(keyOrKeys : string | string[]){
   if(Array.isArray(keyOrKeys){
     // delete all keys in array
   } else {
     // delete single key.
   }
}
```

So, I need to follow good naming conventions. What name should I use in place of 'keyOrkeys'. Or is it just fine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create definition for this function with real overloads (not just one implementation), you can name argument for each overload independently, e.g.:

```
delete(key : string): void; // or whatever you are returning
delete(keys : string[]): void;
// this is useful for calling inside another function with union parameter
delete(keyOrKeys : string | string[]): void;

delete(keyOrKeys : string | string[]){
   if(Array.isArray(keyOrKeys){
     // delete all keys in array
   } else {
     // delete single key.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `delete` is a reserve keyword in Js. Use `deleteKeys` maybe.

Comment: this was off context but I'll keep in mind next time. Thanks :)